# Matrix Multiplication through operator overloading

Tags: c++

This code shows the address when I run this instead of the multiplication of two matrices.

```
matrix matrix:: operator *(matrix x)
{  
    matrix c(m1,n2);   
    c.m=c.n=m;         
    for(int i=0;i<m1;i++) 
    {        
        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++)        
        {            
            c.a[i][j]=0;           
            for(int k=0;k<n1;k++)
            {
                c.a[i][j]+=(a[i][k]*x.a[k][j]);       
            }   
        } 
    } 
    return c; 
}
```

Comment: This code does not output anything.  Please elaborate on what is going on and provide an [mcve]

Comment: What are m1 and n2?  I expect you intended `m` and `x.n` then the constructor of matrix should be setting `c.m` and `c.n` so you don't want to immediately clobber them.

Comment: Your design is quite inefficient anyway.  Maybe you don't care enough to do the difficult things needed for real efficiency.  But at least do the trivial things to avoid excess inefficiency:  The signature should have been `matrix matrix::operator*(matrix const&x) const`

Answer (score -1):

For two matrices, you can use either a member unary operator *=, i.e.:

```
matrix & operator *= (matrix  const & q)
{
    // ... your code to multiply "this" by q...

    return *this;
}
```

or non-member binary operator:

```
matrix operator * (matrix p, matrix const & q)
{
    return p *= q;
}
```